# Dialogflow and shopify APi notify user after order completed

Tags: shopify, dialogflow-es, shopify-api

I am new to shopify api and have try to integrate dialogflow chat bot with shopify api and I am stuck at this problem. I got a shopify shop link in my dialog flow chatbot that will redirect user to the app and after the user completed the purchase I want the chatbot to also notify the user about it. Is there any method that I can make this happen?
Many thanks.